# I/O settings in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I understand that we have to use:

```
job.setMapperClass()
job.setReducerClass()
job.setMapOutputKeyClass()
job.setMapOutputValueClass()
job.setOuputKeyClass()
job.setOutputKeyValueClass()
```

to avoid type erasure problem in Java generics. But I saw many times that people don't use all of these methods. Some skip `setOuputKey/ValueClass()` and some skip `setOutputKey/ValueClass`.

Why is that? Do we not always have to set all of these methods?

Answer (score 0):

If your map and reduce classes output the same Key / Value types, you only need to set the OutputKeyClass and OutputValueClass (the MapOutputKeyClass and MapOutputValueClass are assumed to be the same as the reducer unless explicitly set).

If you don't set the Mapper or Reducer class, hadoop assumes the default is to use what's called the identify mapper or reducer - which output each input K,V pair they receive (or all values for a particular key in the case of the reducer).